# Can node run in multiple threads?

Tags: node.js, multithreading

Nodejs is asynchronous. But single threaded. When a synchronous workload is executed, the event loop is blocked.

Can we make node multi threaded to increase performance?

Comment: Node is single threaded in most of its aspects. However the underlying event loop library, libuv, uses a threadpool for file system operations or other CPU consuming operations. Do you have any need in particular?

Comment: I want to squeeze out every resource I can because I want to run my laptop as a server which many IoT device would connect to.

Comment: But that's the perfect use case for the event-loop. You can read more about the event loop used by NodeJS [here](https://dev.to/khaosdoctor/node-js-under-the-hood-3-deep-dive-into-the-event-loop-135d). You should perhaps run some benchmarks to determine you indeed need a better solution than this.

Comment: you can use `worker_threads` module there are many examples online its a relatively new feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look into [`cluster mode`](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) in recent versions of Node.js.

Quoting the example from the above page for reference:

```js
const cluster = require('cluster');
const http = require('http');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

  // Fork workers.
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
  });
} else {
  // Workers can share any TCP connection
  // In this case it is an HTTP server
  http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('hello world\n');
  }).listen(8000);

  console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);
}
```

This code starts a number of workers, and you see a clear separation between `master` and `worker` code.

These processes can communicate by sending messages.